# Passing HTML through JSON (PHP and DOJO)

Tags: php, javascript, json, datagrid, dojo

I have a datastore that is querying a database and outputting JSon... something like this:

```
$data[] = array('id' => $i, 'prod_id' => $product_id, 'link' => $link);
```

I'm wondering how you can pass back a link using the $link variable.  If I had this for example:

```
$link = "<a href=\"google.com\"> Clicky </a>";
```

The datagrid would display  Clicky  and not the actual html link...  Is there anyway to pass back html?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing the link URL and the link text separately, then reconstructing them into an anchor link in JavaScript on the client-side.

You could also try escaping the HTML, then unescaping on the client-side.

I have no idea why it won't send links- perhaps the browser is trying to parse the sent HTML too early?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `formatter` in dojo grid to format the HTML displayed in each cell. When creating the grid, you can set a `formatter` for each column. The `formatter` is a JavaScript function that takes two parameters, the first one `value` means the value of the cell, the second one `rowIndex` means the index of current row. The return value of the `formatter` function is the HTML content displayed in the cell.

For your case, I would suggest that you use a single column for both the link URL and anchor text. You can use a simple encoding, like `http://www.google.com$$$Clicky`, where `$$$` is used to separate these two fields. The PHP code would be:

```
$link = "http://www.google.com$$$Clicky";
```

Then in your `formatter` function, you can use :

```
function(value, rowIndex) {
    var parts = value.split('$$$');
    return "<a href='" + parts[0] + "'>" + parts[1] + "</a>";
}
```

If you prefer to use one column for each field, e.g. `url` for URL and `anchorText` for the anchor text. Then you need to get the value of another column when formatting the cell. Suppose the grid uses the `url` field. Then the `formatter` function may look like below:

```
function(value, rowIndex) {
   var item = grid.getItem(rowIndex); // Get the store item by index, need the reference of the grid.
   var anchorText = grid.store.getValue(item, 'anchorText');
   return "<a href='" + value + "'>" + anchorText + "</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation.  I ended up using the escapeHTMLInData="false", however.. but will keep the formatter function in mind for later! :)

Comment: Ah, escapeHTMLInData='false', I didn't know that before. Thanks for the information. :)